# Wordpress menu, parents children and grandchildren

Tags: php, wordpress, navigation

I am currently working on a nav menu for a wordpress theme using wp_nav_menu.

I have a few questions as I am now STUCK!

This is how I create my menu:

```
wp_nav_menu(array(
    'sort_column' => 'menu_order',
    'menu_class' => 'nav',
    'theme_location' => 'primary-menu'

));
```

which outputs:

```
<div class="nav">
      <ul>
        <li class="page_item page-item-5"><a href="http://localhost/rbawp/?page_id=5">Home</a></li>
        <li class="page_item page-item-7 current_page_item"><a href="http://localhost/rbawp/?page_id=7">Why Renewal</a>
          <ul class='children'>
            <li class="page_item page-item-14"><a href="http://localhost/rbawp/?page_id=14">Fibrex</a>
              <ul class='children'>
                <li class="page_item page-item-22"><a href="http://localhost/rbawp/?page_id=22">What is fibrex</a></li>
                <li class="page_item page-item-24"><a href="http://localhost/rbawp/?page_id=24">History of firex</a></li>
              </ul>
            </li>
            <li class="page_item page-item-16"><a href="http://localhost/rbawp/?page_id=16">What to look for</a></li>
            <li class="page_item page-item-18"><a href="http://localhost/rbawp/?page_id=18">Renewal Warranty</a></li>
            <li class="page_item page-item-20"><a href="http://localhost/rbawp/?page_id=20">Green Seal Cert</a></li>
          </ul>
        </li>
        <li class="page_item page-item-9"><a href="http://localhost/rbawp/?page_id=9">About</a></li>
        <li class="page_item page-item-11"><a href="http://localhost/rbawp/?page_id=11">Windows</a></li>
        <li class="page_item page-item-13"><a href="http://localhost/rbawp/?page_id=13">Doors</a></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
```

So what I am trying to figure out is how can I change the ul 'children' to say 'grandchildren' if the page is a child of a child?

The idea is that their is 3 tiers and when why is clicked the sub menu appears below and when one of the kids is clicked if it has kids then its kids appear below that.

I have tried many work arounds using get_children and get_pages, returning an object and pulling out some of the objects but that takes too long to load and is not practical.

My next question is I have tried to format the output of the wp_nav_menu us item_wrap but I still cannot get it to work.

What I am trying to achieve is to take this http://renewmywindows.com navigation and get it going in wordpress - the jQuery stuff.

I have read through many different boards and posts to try and find an answer but am still stumped.

Thanks,

C

Comment: You could just use a selector like ".children .children" to find the grandchildren. You may not even need to label them as grandchildren to find them.

Comment: Ah now I feel STUPID! how much of an idiot am I!!!!